# What is the difference between Que and Est que

Tags: usage

I am not quite sure what the different uses or situations one might use these words for (que, est-ce, est que).

I believe they all are used in questions like what? I may be wrong. Any clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it's useful to think "que" as "what/that which" and "est[-ce] que" as "is it so that". Examples:

- Qu'est-ce que tu manges? / Que manges-tu? = What are you eating? What is it that you're eating?
- Est-ce que tu manges? = Are you eating (Is it true that you are eating?)

Actually, "que" is not strictly a question word, but a relative pronoun that is often used in question to replace the longer phrase "Qu'est-ce que". Always remember that "Qu'est-ce que" means "What is it that".

Answer (score 2):

### Forming questions with no Interrogative Word

To form Direct Questions with no Interrogative Word one may use three ways (with increasing degree of formality):

a) Rising intonation

> Tu ne déjeunes pas avec nous ?

b) With the est-ce que structure (very common in speach)

> Est-ce que tu va continuer comme ça ?
>
> Est-ce qu'elle l'a compris ?

c) Inversion and link with a hyphen (the most formal)

> L'as-tu vu(e) ?
>
> Est-ce étrange ?
>
> Me reconnaissez-vous ?
>
> La chambre était-elle ouverte ?
>
> Les autres sont-ils partis aussi ?
>
> N'en mange-t-il pas ?

Note the -t- inserted between the verb and the pronoun subject when the verb ends in a vowel as in the last example.

Note that est-ce que is used to form questions with je (for reasons of sound).

So instead of aimé-je, prends-je, etc. (very rare found) one would use (in speach and writing)

> Est-ce que j'aime ? Est-ce que je prends ? etc.

But one may encounter:

> ai-je ? dis-je ? dois-je ? fais-je ? sais-je ? vais-je ? vois-je ?
>   veux-je ?

Also puis-je ? is preffered to peux-je ?

---

### Que

Que may have various grammatical functions.

a) Adverb in exclamations:

> Que je suis heureux !

b) Conjuction:

> Je sais qu'il est là. Je souhaite qu'il soit là.
>
> Qu'il meure !
>
> Que Dieu vous bénisse !

c) Interrogative pronoun

> Que faites-vous ? Qu'est-ce que vous faites ?

d) Relative pronoun (object). Compare:

> L'homme qui parle est le président.
>
> L'homme que je vois parler est le président.

---

### Que in direct questions

Que as an interrogative pronoun is used to form (direct) questions as complement of things (or where what is meant).

> Que deviendra ma fille ?
>
> Qu'est-ce / Qu'est-ce que c'est ?
>
> Qu'êtes-vous ?
>
> Qu'est ce qu'il y a dans le tiroir ?
>
> Que se passe-t-il ?
>
> Que m'importe ?

Qu'est-ce que is used to ask for a definition.

> Qu'est-ce que la thermodynamique ?

In conversation the form qu'est-ce que c'est que is sometimes used to make an emphatic inquiry?

> Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette chose-là ? (Petit Prince, Saint-Exypéry)

---

### Suggestions for Further reading

1) https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-70800.php

2) https://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/K_b_phrase_interr.htm

3) https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/podcast/forme-interrogative-quest-ce-que-quoi-que-present.html

4) https://www.thoughtco.com/questions-in-french-1368935

5) https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/la-phrase/la-phrase-interrogative

6) http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/relative_pronouns.shtml

7) https://www.thoughtco.com/different-uses-of-que-1368934

8) http://frenchyourway.com.au/how-to-use-qui-and-que-in-french

9) https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/relative-pronouns-que-qui/

---

### References

1) A French Reference Grammar (H. Ferrar).

2) A Student Grammar of French (M. Offold).